# Fetch and Add description wrong?

Tags: multithreading, locking, atomic

I am trying to understand how to use fetch and add (atomic operation) in a lock implementation.

I came across this article in Wikipedia, I found it duplicated in at least one other place.   The implementation does not make sense and looks to me to have a bug or more in it.  Of course I could be missing a subtle point and not really understanding what is being described.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetch-and-add

---

```
    << atomic >>
    function FetchAndAdd(address location, int inc) {
        int value := *location
        *location := value + inc
        return value
    }

   record locktype {
        int ticketnumber
        int turn
     }
     procedure LockInit( locktype* lock ) {
        lock.ticketnumber := 0
        lock.turn := 0
     }
     procedure Lock( locktype* lock ) {
        int myturn := FetchAndIncrement( &lock.ticketnumber ) //must be atomic, since many threads might ask for a lock at the same time
        while lock.turn ≠ myturn 
            skip // spin until lock is acquired
     }
     procedure UnLock( locktype* lock ) {
        FetchAndIncrement( &lock.turn ) //this need not be atomic, since only the possessor of the lock will execute this
     }
```

---

According to the article they first do LockInit.  FetchAndIncrement calls FetchAndAdd with inc set to 1.

If this does not contain a bug I do not understand how it could possibly work.

The first thread to access it will get it:

lock.ticketnumber = 1
lock.turn = 0.

Let's say 5 more accesses to the lock happen before it is released.

lock.ticketnumber = 6
lock.turn = 0

First thread releases the lock.

lock.ticketnumber = 6
lock.turn = 1

Next thread comes in and the status would be

lock.ticketnumber = 7
lock.turn = 1

And the returned value: myturn = 6 (lock.ticketnumber before the faa).

In this case the:

while lock.turn ≠ myturn

can never be true.

Is there a bug in this illustration or am I missing something?

If there is a bug in this implementation what would fix it?

Thanx

Julian

Answer (score -1):

Dang it, I see it now.   I found it referring to a general description of the algorithm and then I looked at it more closely.

When a thread calls Lock it spins waiting on the value it got back, for some reason I was thinking it kept calling that function.

When it spins it waits until another thread increments turn and eventually becomes the number of myturn.

Sorry for wasting your time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_lock